# Sencha ExtJS API - very slow loading

Tags: api, extjs

**strong text**I am new to Sencha and I am evaluating it.

Every time I try to open a browser and visit the API page at docs.sencha.com/whatever ... it takes forever to load up.

I mean, what the hell is it doing at the back end? Is it taking that long to load up all the necessary extjs app files? Or is it loading me the whole API library while I am only try to see one page?

So far, I have gone through a couple of examples, and I like Sencha a lot . However, I have a concern about the loading speed in production, because the speed they load up the API scares me.

If you are experienced with Sencha, could you tell me what is going on at the back? Please don't say "API is 20MB big, takes time to load ...", because I only want to see one page per visit, i believe it is wrong to load me the whole API to initialize a page.

[image: loading...]

UPDATE ------------------------------------

I face this loading screen for **20-30 seconds** everytime when I open the browser. IE only. Chrome and FF are fast??

UPDATE 2 ----------------------------------

[image: profiling]

I did a profiling for IE. Btween `http://projects.sencha.com/auth/session?...`  and `/architect/2guides/intro/README.js?...` IE went to sleep for over 20 seconds blank doing nothing (as u can see from the highlighted blank gap in between the 2 rows in the picture), then suddenly came back and finish loading the rest of the page!

I copied those links 1 by 1 and load them up in a new IE window. They all individually came up in milliseconds, so there is no speed issue. It is just that, IE went to sleep for 20+ seconds (CPU monitor shows no activity) StranGe!

Comment: Must be some kind of connection problem, it loads in a few seconds for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're starting up, you should definitely start building your application using `sencha cmd`. This allows you to build a version of the extjs file that uses only the components that you use.

But as a side note. I use the full sencha api and it takes me less than 2 sec to load the whole API. I use the production version ext-all.js and ext-all.css and gzip everything. After the zipping, I get a file size of less than 500KB, which is like nothing actually.

**EDIT:**

I checked the API docs page. The total download size is less than 1 MB and that too cause there are a lot of icons which aren't combined as sprites. Hence the browser takes a lot of time in requesting the icons. That's why the page is slow.

For IE, well sencha can't do much about it. The browser itself is slow. Any webpage you load will suffer from the same problem. Not just sencha's. The page speed will improve if you do some optimizations. The size of the API isn't the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I will do more research about *IE* :P

Comment: **warning** You'd rather want to kill yourself.. :P